# merge and sum two dataframes where columns match python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I might be approaching this is the wrong way. If I have two dataframes a and b:

Dataframe A:

```
a b c
1 2 4
1 6 5
1 8 7
```

and Dataframe B:

```
a b c d
1 2 4 9
1 6 5 7
1 8 7 10
```

And I want to join them, but cruically sum the columns where the column name matchs, and keep the column names that don't match. So the final joined table would look like:

```
a   b   c   d
2   4   8   9
2   12  10  7
2   16  14  10
```

Note: The indexs would always match (i.e the same number of records in the same order)

Comment: your output doesn't match your input dfs, df B is missing `10` in column `d`, also in this case you can just do `df1.add(df, fill_value=df1)`

Comment: Actually this works: `df1.add(df).fillna(df1)`

Comment: How would you do this if the indices on `df` and `df1` do not match (but the columns still do)? I'm getting all `NaN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) on the larger df passing in the other df and call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [18]:
df1.add(df).fillna(df1)

Out[18]:
   a   b   c   d
0  2   4   8   9
1  2  12  10   7
2  2  16  14  10
```

Another way is to use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first):

```
In [20]:
df1.add(df).combine_first(df1)

Out[20]:
   a   b   c   d
0  2   4   8   9
1  2  12  10   7
2  2  16  14  10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can align the dataframe, fill NAN with zero and perform simple addition.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['a','b','c','d'])
d, d2 = d.align(d2, fill_value=0)
sum_df = d + d2

In [23]: d
Out[23]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  4  0
1  1  6  5  0
2  1  8  7  0

In [24]: d2
Out[24]: 
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  4   9
1  1  6  5   7
2  1  8  7  10

In [25]:sum_df
Out[25]: 
   a   b   c   d
0  2   4   8   9
1  2  12  10   7
2  2  16  14  10
```